# Parse JSON without tree

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON like this.

```
[
  {"latitude":40.91769,"longtitude":29.18127},
  {"latitude":40.91863,"longtitude":29.18149},
  {"latitude":40.91868,"longtitude":29.18153},
   ///-------///
  {"latitude":40.91423,"longtitude":29.18741},
  {"latitude":40.91471,"longtitude":29.18587}
]
```

But I don't have a structure like an tree. It's more like an array. How can i parse it latitude and longitude one by one?

Comment: What did you try and what is not working for you?

Comment: This requires very basic of Json parsing. Did you try anything so far? Please try on your own first.  This has very nicely explained answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: post your android code here.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was an candidate of an upvote? I can see one +1 and one -1

Comment: Its simple `Json Parsing`.

Comment: Please do some research. spoon feeding should not allowed here.

Comment: Sorry guys now i recognized i couldn't my problem clearly. But Mahit's solution works for me. Thanks all of you.

Comment: Its Mohit not Mahit.By the way welcome...

Comment: Is my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void parseJson(String json) {
    try {       
            JSONArray root = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject att = (JSONObject) root.getJSONObject(i);
                String lat = att.getString("latitude");
                String log = att.getString("longtitude");

            }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct but spoon feeding is a bad Idea. I hope you understand.

Comment: @Mohit thanks it works for me